# checkbox could not uncheck php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have written a code to save the check values of checkboxes to database.

check condition is working fine as in the checked values are saving to database when submit and it keeps checked when submit and refresh.

But when it uncheck and submit then refresh the page the checkbox still keeps remained checked. It won't saved the status of unchecked.

I include a chunk code which is related to this issue. If anyone can get the issue that'd be great.

```
echo "<form action='' class='' method='post'><tr>";
   $sql_stamp = "SELECT check_list FROM time_stamps WHERE nJobNumber=".$nJobNumber;
                $query_stamp = $conn->prepare($sql_stamp);
                $query_stamp->execute();
                $numRows = $query_stamp->rowCount(); 
                if($numRows > 0){
                    $row_stamp = $query_stamp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $checkboxes = explode(',',$row_stamp['check_list']);
                    echo ' <td><center> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="shop_drawing" '.(in_array( "shop_drawing",$checkboxes) ? "checked=checked" : "").'></td>';
                    echo ' <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="site_measure" '.(in_array( "site_measure",$checkboxes) ? "checked=checked" : "").'></td>';
                    echo ' <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="shop_drawings_approved" '.(in_array( "shop_drawings_approved",$checkboxes) ? "checked =checked" : "").'></td>';
                    echo '<td><center> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" id="check" value="batch" '.(in_array( "batch",$checkboxes) ? "checked=checked" : "").'></td>';
                    echo '<td><center> <input type="text" name="batch_no"><br>  </td>';
                    echo ' <td><center> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/> </td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="job_number[result]" value="'."true".'"</td>'; 
                    echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="job_number[number]" value="'.$nJobNumber.'"</td>';
                }else{
                    echo '<td><center><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" id="check" value="shop_drawing"></td>';
                    echo '<td><center><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" id="check" value="site_measure"></td>';
                    echo '<td><center><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" id="check" value="shop_drawings_approved"> </td>';
                    echo '<td><center> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" id="check" value="batch"></td>';
                    echo '<td><center> <input type="text" name="batch_no"><br>  </td>';
                    echo "<td><center> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></td>";
                    echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="job_number[result]" value="'."false".'"</td>'; 
                    echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="job_number[number]" value="'.$nJobNumber.'"</td>'; 
                }


                echo "</tr> </form>";
            }
        echo "</tbody> </table>";

      ?>
```

Insert values to database:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $checkbox = $_POST["check_list"];
        $job_number = $_POST["job_number"];
        $batch_no = $_POST["batch_no"];
        date_default_timezone_set('Australia');
        $date_time = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
        //$username = "$SESSION[userid]";
        if($job_number["result"] == "true"){



 if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) 


 {
                       $checkboxes = implode(",",$_POST['check_list']);
                        $stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE time_stamps SET time_date=?,username=?, batch_no=?,check_list=? WHERE nJobNumber=?');
                        $stmt->bind_param('ssssi',$date_time,$username,$batch_no,$checkboxes,$job_number["number"]);
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
        }

    else{

        if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) 

        {
                        $checkboxes = implode(",",$_POST['check_list']);
                        $stmt = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO time_stamps (nJobNumber,time_date,username,batch_no,check_list) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
                        $stmt->bind_param('issss',$job_number["number"],$date_time,$username,$batch_no,$checkboxes);
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                }

            }
```

Basically, What's my requirement is when a user uncheck a 'checked' checkbox it should be unchecked when submit the form (after a refresh). But in my case it keeps checked.

Comment: your update and/or insert failed then and you should check for the reason why by using proper error handling.

Comment: You don't appear to actually have a `<form>` tag anywhere, and `<form>` is **not** a valid child of `<tbody`> (which is where yours appears as though it would be based on your `</form>`). If you want the values to submit, you'll need to make use of that element for your `submit` button to trigger (or make use of some AJAX).

Comment: Actually I do have a form. I did not mention it in the code above. I have updated my code in the question @Obsidian Age

Comment: Do you really have a CSV value in `time_stamps.check_list`? That's generally a very bad idea for a relational database

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes don't submit any data in a form payload. If you don't check **any** checkboxes, `$_POST['check_list']` will be empty and neither your `INSERT` nor `UPDATE` queries will execute.

Comment: What I need is when a user uncheck a 'checked' checkbox it should be unchecked when submit the form. But in my case it keeps checked. Did you get what I'm saying? @Phil

Comment: You need to remove this condition: `if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))` around your `UPDATE` query so that if a user has no checkboxes checked they will be cleared in the database

Comment: @Nick I think that's on the right track but OP will need to make sure whatever they pass to `implode()` is an array

Comment: @Phil you are absolutely right... that line should be rewritten `$checkboxes = empty($_POST['check_list']) ? '' : implode(",",$_POST['check_list']);`

Comment: Yo @Nick you're totally right. Would you mind posting your comment as the answer. Then I can accept it as the correct answer. You're a legend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of your queries will execute if the user submits a form with no checkboxes checked. While this may be ok for your `INSERT` query, it will not allow the `check_list` field to be updated. So you will need to change the code for updates from this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    $checkboxes = implode(",",$_POST['check_list']);
    $stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE time_stamps SET time_date=?,username=?, batch_no=?,check_list=? WHERE nJobNumber=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssi',$date_time,$username,$batch_no,$checkboxes,$job_number["number"]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

to this:

```
$checkboxes = empty($_POST['check_list']) ? '' : implode(",",$_POST['check_list']);
$stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE time_stamps SET time_date=?,username=?, batch_no=?,check_list=? WHERE nJobNumber=?');
$stmt->bind_param('ssssi',$date_time,$username,$batch_no,$checkboxes,$job_number["number"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

You may also want to change the insert code in the same way if you want to insert a record even when the user doesn't check any checkboxes.

Thanks to @Phil for his input.

Comment: Hello @Nick When I changed my code as you mentioned, checkbox 'checked' condition not working. Now the uncheck condition is working fine. I updated the question would you mind having a look please?

Comment: Hi Matt, you need to change the assignment of `$checkboxes` too did you do that?

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see a couple of problems.  I see this line:

```
$job_number = $_POST["job_number"];
```

But then I see you use this:

```
if($job_number["result"] == "true"){
```

So I ask, is $job_number an array or just a string/value?

Also, unchecked checkboxes don't submit a value.  And since you test for a not empty $_POST['check_list'] value your UPDATE will never run.  Remove the ! character.

Comment: `$job_number` is an array from `name="job_number[result]"` and `name="job_number[number]"`

Comment: Removing the ! character means the query won't run of the user does check any checkboxes

Comment: The empty test is what needs to be done away with.  The array will be empty if no checkboxes are checked.